# Обработка GPS координат из txt-файла на Python

Tags: python, строки, файлы, gps, координаты

У меня есть файл tkpt_dict.txt это координаты формата "Широта, Долгота" для каждой точки

```
56.6656332229853,-4.07549094973673
56.6654706790411,-4.07715475708222
56.6658433607951,-4.0803983938441
56.6657085935658,-4.08308369800892
56.6656913596524,-4.08679545454817
56.6656592305536,-4.08871123027875
56.6654891203157,-4.08947699433228
56.6655907727544,-4.09278733564568
56.6654648415451,-4.09359632994024
56.6657530084886,-4.09516268121721
56.6661261281559,-4.09701937330206
56.666583500041,-4.09920718895852
56.6668895070955,-4.10013813805868
56.6665747421354,-4.09919364584093
56.6661293622529,-4.09704076876584
56.665744414777,-4.09513935667372
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы рассчитать дистанцию между точками по формуле  [geopy.distance](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) (наиболее подходит по точности)

Имеется данный кусок кода:

```
import geopy.distance
i = 0
y = 1
with open('obj/tkpt_dict.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        with open('obj/distance.txt', 'a') as distance_file:
            distance = int(round(geopy.distance.distance(float(line[i]), float(line[y])).m, 0))
            distance_file.write(str(distance))
            i += 1
            y += 1
```

Но код выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Python/Project1/31-gps-m.py", line 11, in <module>
distance=int(round(geopy.distance.distance(float(line[i]),float(line[y])).m, 0))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

Нужно как-то данные из txt-файла перенести в формулу

```
distance = int(round(geopy.distance.distance(точка1), точка2).m, 0))
```

и полученные результаты внести в out-файл distance.txt

Comment: Как именно Вам нужно рассчитать дистанцию? Между 1 и 2, 3 и 4 и т. д. точками. Или между 1 и 2, 2 и 3, и т. д?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я уже просто не видел другого варианта заставить понимать значения из файла. Это были последние попытки моего мозга)

Comment: У Вас нечётной количество точек, уточните, пожалуйста, как именно нужно считать дистанцию.

Comment: @nomnoms12 1-2,2-3,3-4 и т.д. А то что нечетное количество это для примера. там количество вплоть до 2тыс шт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```py
import geopy.distance


coords = []
with open('tkpt_dict.txt') as f_inp:
    lines = f_inp.readlines()

    for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
        x1, y1 = map(float, lines[i].split(', '))
        x2, y2 = map(float, lines[i+1].split(', '))

        coords.append(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))

with open('distance.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for x, y in coords:
        distance = str(round(geopy.distance.distance(x, y).m))
        f_out.write(distance + '\n')
```